# How can I create a script that asks a user for the following data: number id, username, name, and mail

Tags: bash, scripting, users

How can I create a bash script that asks a user for the following data: number id, username, name, and mail, and then put the info on a new line on a file called users.txt with this format?

I want to put multiple lines on this file with this format.

cat /root/users.txt

> 00000001:richardstallman:Richard.Stallman:richardstallman@gnu.org

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just parse `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
read -p "Enter your number id: " numid
read -p "Enter your username: " Uname
read -p "Enter your name: " name
read -p "Enter your email address: " Email

echo "${numid}:${Uname}:${name}:${Email}" >> file
```

read takes user input and sets it to a variable, with -p it can ask a question in one line as well.  Then it simply echo's the information into your file.